# Modifying elements from a HashMap of HashMaps

Tags: java

Say I have

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

then I access an element as

```
Integer foo = mapOfMaps.get('what').get('ever');
```

and finally I change the value of `foo`, e.g.:

```
foo++;
```

Then if I want to see that value updated in the hashmap, I should do something as

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = mapOfMaps.get('what');
```

And then `put` the new value as

```
map.put('ever', foo);
```

This works, if I access `mapOfMaps.get('what').get('ever')` I'll get the updated value. But my question is: why I don't have to `put` `map`  into `mapOfMaps`? (i.e.:)

```
mapOfMaps.put('what', map);
```

Comment: Your variable `map` is already referring to the same `HashMap` object that is already inside `mapOfMaps`.

Comment: @rgettman and why is `foo` not doing the same? It is an object too right? Would this have been different if instead of type `Integer` had been another type? Why is `map` a "reference" and `foo` a "value"?

Comment: Because foo in integer which is immutable

Comment: @vmaroli didn't know that concept, I'm new to Java, but indeed that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `map` is already referring to the same `HashMap` object that is already inside `mapOfMaps`.

```
HashMap mapOfMaps:
    "what" -> (HashMap)  <- map
        "ever" -> (Integer) 1  <- foo
```

When you retrieve the value `foo` refers to the `Integer` value stored in the map, until you execute `foo++`.  Because `Integer`s are immutable, what `foo++` really does is unbox it, increment it, and box it again to another `Integer`.  Now `foo` refers to another `Integer` object representing the new value.

```
HashMap mapOfMaps:
    "what" -> (HashMap)  <- map
        "ever" -> (Integer) 1         foo -> 2
```

This explains why you need to `put` the value 2 back into `map`.

But `map` is not modified to refer to another HashMap; it's still referring to the same `HashMap` that's still in `mapOfMaps`.  This means that it doesn't need to be `put` back into `mapOfMaps` like `2` needed to be re-`put` back into `map`.